# Similar to other questions on DATE ISSUES in Excel but

Tags: microsoft-excel, format, date

when I type in dates I get something totally different.  for example I type in `012517` (jan 2, 2017) and I get `4/8/1934`.

It changes with each date I put in. I have tried the *"solutions"* provided elsewhere but still same switcheroo.

I have reapplied the cell formatting for dates and location and still nada.

This happened to me all the time as well in 2010 version and I just updated recently to 2013 and gee - still a problem!  please advise!

Comment: you probably need to type `01/25/17` rather than `012517` since Excel will treat the second as a number, not a date.

Answer (score 1):

That's expected behavior. Excel counts dates as numbers from January 1st, 1900 (or January 1st, 1904 if you have the Mac option checked). The number `12517`, if you count forward (and include the non-existent leap day in 1900) is April 8th, 1934, exactly as Excel is showing you.

If you really want to enter the dates without slashes, there are some workarounds, but nothing built-in.

1. You could use a second column with a formula that converts your number to the date. Something like `=DATE(2000 + RIGHT(A1, 2), LEFT(RIGHT("0" & A1, 6), 2), MID(RIGHT("0" & A1, 6), 3, 2))`
2. You could use some VBA in the `Worksheet_Change` event to pull apart the number you just entered and replace it with a date.
3. You can enter the numbers as you want, then go back and use Excel's Text to Columns on them. On the third step of the wizard, specify that the column data format is a date.
4. There is some format trickery you can use so that Excel will put slashes into the numbers you type, but I would not recommend it because Excel will not understand that they are dates. If you absolutely must, you can set the custom format of the cell to `00\/00\/00`, but, again, *this is not a date, you can not reformat it to show a year, and date-based worksheet functions will not work on it*.